# Error create file using FileFolderService in Alfresco

Tags: createfile

I am trying to create a file using FileFolderService in alfresco, But I am getting exception and the details are provided below. So can anyone help me!

Site name: mysite 
File Name: will be passed as request parameter and a new file with the passed in value to be created in Document library of the site.

**Code snippet:**

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) ctx.getBean("ServiceRegistry");
FileFolderService fileFolderService = serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService();
String fileName = req.getParameter("fileName");
NodeRef folder = new NodeRef("avm://mysite/-1;www;avm_webapps;ROOT;documentLibrary");
fileFolderService.create(folder, fileName, ContentModel.TYPE_CONTAINER);
```

**Exception thrown:**

```
ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-8080-exec-4] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 11100002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 11100016 Invalid node type for AVM.
 org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 11100002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 11100016 Invalid node type for AVM.
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:433)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:433)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:495)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:533)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:349)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:377)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)
```

Comment: Why are you looking for a documentLibrary folder in the AVM? It's true that Share used to store dashboard info in a special AVM store, but that is no longer used and the document library content has never been stored in AVM.

Comment: Will Abson,Thanks for your quick response. All I wanted to do is create a file in "Company Home > mysite > test" folder. So can you please let me what is wrong in my code. Or a better way of doing it.

Comment: I could get this issue resolved by making change in my code as follows<br/><code>                                                 ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) ctx.getBean("ServiceRegistry");
FileFolderService fileFolderService = serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService();
String fileName = req.getParameter("fileName");
NodeRef folder = new NodeRef("workspace/SpacesStore/Company%20Home/Sites/mysite/Test");
fileFolderService.create(folder, fileName, ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT);</code>

Comment: You are getting there but I'm not sure how that will work. You cannot create a nodeRef unless you know the GUID of the node. If all you have is a path then you need to first get the root node, then retrieve the target folder using the root node and a path, and then finally create the content item.

Comment: Added potential solution below

Comment: Where are you getting "ctx" (for ctx.getBean()) from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to access items in the DM repository using AVM-like paths. If you do not understand the difference between the two then I would suggest doing some background reading such as the *Professional Alfresco* book.

You could try something like the following code, but I have not tested this myself.

```
String siteName = "blah", newFile = "My New File";
String path = "app:company_home/st:sites/cm:" + siteName + "/cm:documentLibrary";
List<String> pathElements = Arrays.asList(str.split("/"));
NodeRef rootNode = nodeService.getRootNode(new StoreRef("workspace", "SpacesStore"));
NodeRef dlNode = fileFolderService.resolveNamePath(rootNode, pathElements);
NodeRef newNode = fileFolderService.create(dlNode, newFile, ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT).getNodeRef();
```

You will want to set some properties and content for the node, but that will at least create it for you. You can find more examples in the Alfresco FirstFoundationClient SDK project.

Exactly how you inject the objects `nodeService` and `fileFolderService` depends on what container your code is running in, but in the case of a Java-backed web script then you can inject in the dependencies via Spring config by referencing the `NodeService` and `FileFolderService` beans. Try to avoid using the `serviceRegistry` if you can.